# Brackets-shell custom application extension

Tags: brackets-shell

Maybe I'm a bit confused here. I've built a custom extension which consists of the following files:

```
|--myapp
|       |--main.js
|--node
        |----SimpleDomain.js
```

If I install these as an an extension and run the Brackets app my extension works as expected.

I now want to build a custom app, the question is where do I put these files so that it becomes part of my custom application?

Regards,

Carl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carl,  See here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/brackets-dev/BKVA8MIqXzk.   Then here https://github.com/alloyking/node-app-brackets/tree/master